# How to tell the user what their options are when they forget their password and there is not the option to reset it through the web or email?

Tags: user-expectation, password-recovery, password-change

There is a system where users can set a web password through the application they have on their cellphones. So if they forget the password they can easily reset it through the app with no problem. Another way to reset a password is to call the support center, and they create a password and text it to the user. For some reason (for one I can say the users don't use their email to register), there is not the option to reset or send the password through the email. So, what should be done? How should we inform the user that if they have forgotten their password what the options they have are? Here are some solutions coming to my mind:

- A link saying "Forgot password" to another page explaining the options to them
- A button saying "what to do in case of forgetting my password" or something like that and by clicking it a message shows up in place explaining the options the user has.
- As the options are limited, always show them under the login button

Answer (score 1):

A "Forgot Password?" Link is usually the cleanest way to provide a set of options to the user. When the user clicks the link you can then show a screen with full details on all the options.

Comment: I see, but since the options aren't that much, isn't it bad to send users to another page? where they only can _read_ something? isn't it better to show the options on the same page? Since opening a new page doesn't provide them with any form or link they can click on or use to reset their password, won't it be deceiving if they are sent to another page anyway?

Comment: The first rule of UX screen design is that every screen should serve a single purpose, and as resetting a password is a different action than logging in. It's also your corner case... in most cases the user will just be logging in and everything else is just noise. You obviously need some sort of link or button to help the user if they have forgotten but that's all you need.

Comment: Oh wait... on the forgot password screen is there not the link/button to phone? (And or other actions to reset?) if there are no actions then yes the screen will be awkward - there needs to be actions the user can take.

Comment: exactly!! The problem is that they cannot do anything online with the browser. They just have to call the support center or change the password or change it through the application they have on their phone. So the other page would be just plain text with no button or action explaining to them the two options they have for resetting the password...

Comment: But the call to the support center, can you not put that button/link on the "reset options" screen? Eg "Call <a href="tel:18005551234">1-800-555-1234</a> to reset your password, or blah blah blah..."

Comment: What if they are visiting the site on their laptops?

Comment: Skype will open